# Unusual behaviour of ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

Today i was trying angular directive ngFor. The problem i am facing is that when i select any checkbox (for e.g. 0) and click "next" , if next question also have the same option   (0)  as i have selected in previous question then it will be checked automatically, i dont know how?? [This behaviour is not seen if any two or more consecutive questions doesnt have alteast one same option. ]. I hope it make sense. here is my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/D5Q4u9Q6sKGvdrRVGF0q?p=preview)

**template:**

```
    {{question}}
    <div *ngFor="let option of options">
      <input type="checkbox">{{option}}<br>
    </div>

  <button (click)="onNext()">next</button>
```

**Component.ts**

```
export class App implements OnInit {
    private questionPaper = {
        questions: [{
                _id: "59d1cbd4f8a709358c045696",
                question: "2 + 3",
                __v: 0,
                answers: [
                    "5"
                ],
                options: [
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "5",
                    "3",
                    "6"
                ]
            },
            {
                _id: "59d1cbf7f8a709358c045698",
                question: "1 * 3",
                __v: 0,
                answers: [
                    "3"
                ],
                options: [
                    "1",
                    "3",
                    "0",
                    "4"
                ]
            },
            {
                _id: "59d1cc18f8a709358c045699",
                question: "3 - 3",
                __v: 0,
                answers: [
                    "0"
                ],
                options: [
                    "3",
                    "0",
                    "6",
                    "4",
                    "7"
                ]
            },
            {
                _id: "59d1cc3ef8a709358c04569a",
                question: "6 - 4",
                __v: 0,
                answers: [
                    "2"
                ],
                options: [
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4",
                    "0",
                    "6"
                ]
            },
            {
                _id: "59d1cc71f8a709358c04569b",
                question: "4 * 8",
                __v: 0,
                answers: [
                    "32"
                ],
                options: [
                    "4",
                    "8",
                    "12",
                    "32",
                    "23"
                ]
            },
            {
                _id: "59d1cc96f8a709358c04569c",
                question: "0 * 1",
                __v: 0,
                answers: [
                    "0"
                ],
                options: [
                    "0",
                    "1",
                    "10",
                    "-1",
                    "4"
                ]
            },
            {
                _id: "59d1cccdf8a709358c04569d",
                question: "6 + 6",
                __v: 0,
                answers: [
                    "12"
                ],
                options: [
                    "6",
                    "12",
                    "21",
                    "0"
                ]
            },
            {
                _id: "59d1fb6a253c5270115f4ced",
                question: "1 + 10",
                __v: 0,
                answers: [
                    "11"
                ],
                options: [
                    "11"
                ]
            }
        ]
    };

    private question;
    private options = [];
    private currentQuesNumber = 1;
    onInit() {}
    constructor() {
        this.question = this.questionPaper.questions[0].question;
        this.options = this.questionPaper.questions[0].options;

    }

    onNext() {

        if (this.currentQuesNumber >= this.questionPaper.questions.length) {
            this.loadQuestion(this.questions.length);

        } else {

            this.currentQuesNumber = this.currentQuesNumber + 1;
            this.loadQuestion(this.currentQuesNumber);

        }
    }



    loadQuestion(quesNumbToLoad) {
        if (quesNumbToLoad > 0 && quesNumbToLoad <= this.questionPaper.questions.length) {
            this.question = this.questionPaper.questions[quesNumbToLoad - 1].question;

            this.options = this.questionPaper.questions[quesNumbToLoad - 1].options;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the indented behavior because angular resuses DOM elements inside it's `ngForOf`-directive for better performance, based on the **object identity** of the value. So in your case the value is a *string*, that means the **object identity** is its value.

Therefore **angular** is reusing the DOM element if the value of an option is the same between questions. Because the same DOM element is used the checkbox state is still *checked*.

If you want **angular** to not reuse DOM elements inside an `ngForOf`-directive, you have to provide a function which always returns some sort of a unqiue id (*e.g. the current datetime*) and apply it to the `ngForTrackBy` input of the `ngForOf`-directive (short-syntax `trackBy`).

---

*For example:*

**Component**

```
public trackById(index: number, value: any) {
  return Date.now();
}
```

**Component template**

```
*ngFor="let option of options;trackBy:trackById"
```

or:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-option [ngForOf]="options"[ngForTrackBy]="trackByFn">
</ng-template>
```

---

Now angular doesn't reuse any DOM elements for this `ngForOf`-directive.

More about the change propagation of the `ngForOf`-directive can be found in the [**docs**](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation) *(and some useful other stuff about it)*.

---

> Note: This also works also the opposite way. For example if you have some immutable data and you don't want new DOM elements to be created on every change. Just provide a function which returns the current index of the item. This will force **angular** into reusing every existing DOM-element inside your `ngForOf`-directive regardless of the **object identity**.

Comment: @cyrix thanks for your help but now i am facing another problem. I am using *ngFor with md-checkbox (angular material) but after applying 'trackBy' function i am not able to select any checkbox at all. :(